# Determine customers who have transacted at atleast seven different locations within 72 hours -- Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a database of transactions which has following columns :

```
Cust_Num, Transaction_id, Transaction_date, Transaction_Amount, Transaction_location
```

I have to find out customers who have done transactions at at least `7` different locations within a span of `72` hours using Hive

Sample Data:

```
Cust_Num---Transaction_id---Transaction_date---Transaction_Amount,---Transaction_location

123-----------------A01-----------2018-01-01 23:45:36---------10-------------------------------ABC
```